# JAXB: Generate XML from Java using XSD that contains less attributes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am looking for a way to use a generic XML generator from Java classes, and be able to generate XML with given previous version of the Java class, if possible, using XSD.

Example:

Today I would create `Object1` with properties `Property1` and `Property2`, I would generate it's XSD using JAXB and name it today.xsd.
Tomorrow I would like to add `Property3` to `Object1` and I would create a new XSD file and name it tomorrow.xsd. After this, I would like to be able to generate XML with data using both versions of the Object1 with 2 properties or with 3 properties, if possible by using the generated XSDs.

My real case uses lots of classes with lots of properties, and the number of versioning may be a big number.
I would like to store XSDs for each version and generate XMLs from Java classes by dynamically specifying XSD name that will contain version number.

Is it possible to implement my requirement described above, or do you have a similar solution to cover my need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAXB is quite a rigid framework and doesn't support what you want to do.

There are a few approaches when you need to support different versions of the same "object"

- You can manually parse the xml (by manually I mean using XPath), this will give you a lot of flexibility
- Another approach, which is more strict in the validation, but it requires a bit more effort is to have several XSDs which you need to generate manually and then using XSLT you can transform the different XML messages, which are validated with the XSDs, to a "standard" XML, and this XML is the one that you map using JAXB. There are some variations of this pattern in which you funnel different versions into the version that your application expects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't dislike @Augusto's answer above, but I think the problem is generating the XSD with JAXB, because that is going to be inflexible.
It will not work in all cases, but for the relatively simple evolution you are describing, you should be able to write (manually) an XSD that preserve backward-compatibility with the previous days XSD's, where essentially the new properties are always optional. By re-generating the JAXB classes from that newest XSD, you should be able to read the xml from any point in time, into the latest JAXB classes.